# Laravel define join relation as a model relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a scenario:

```
Movie::join('stream_urls', function ($join) {
        $join->on('stream_urls.movie', '=', 'movies.filename');
});
```

I want to define it as a function in the model as I want joined data to be returned as a JSON array. So I want something like this;

```
$movie = Movie::where('is_active', 1)
        ->with('urls')
        ->orderBy('movies.id', 'DESC')->get();
```

How to define this 'urls()' function in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a relationship in the `Movie` model.

This looks like a [one to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

If you stick to naming conventions you only need to specify the class

```php
hasMany(Child::class);
```

But since you use the `stream_url.movie` and `movie.filename` columns, you're going to need to specify them as the optional parameters.

```php
hasMany(Child::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

I'm assuming the model mapping the table `stream_urls` is called `StreamUrl`.

```php
class Movie extends Model
{
    public function urls()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(StreamUrl::class, 'movie', 'filename');
    }
}
```

Now you can eager load this relationship by using `Movie::with('urls')`.